# I can't find the directory 100ANDRO on my pc

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, images, internal-sd

I was wondering why I can not find the folder 100ANDRO that contains the pictures that I take with the smartphone if I connect the phone with the pc.
I premise that this happens only with the directory on the sdcard (that I set as main storage for the photos I take), in fact I have two of this directories , one on the phone storage, the other one on the sd, both are inside a main directory called DCIM.
The problem is that if I use a file manager on the phone I can see every directory, differently on the pc the directory DCIM on the sd doesn't contain anything , consequently I can't see the picture I take apart from the case I move then to the internal storage.
Do you have any idea ?

ps: I've already activated the option to show any hidden directory on the pc but nothing changed

Comment: Maybe it's in `/DCIM/Camera` rather than `/DCIM/100ANDRO`.

Comment: I've checked a thousand times but unfortunately the correct directory is 100ANDRO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera photos should be in DCIM/Camera not in 100ANDRO, but however here is the thing that might help you:
Go to settings>apps and find apps "media storage" and "external storage" and clear cache and data for them, after that reboot your phone and wait up to 10 minutes for android to index all files, then connect phone to PC via USB and see if files are there.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue where there are no files in DCIM folder on the sd card when connected to PC. I'm using a Sony Xperia Z3. I switched the connection mode from Transfer files(MTP) mode to Mass storage mode(MSC) and that enabled me to get to the files.